# craft 3 CMS dont run on production "Craft requires PHP 7.0 or later."

Tags: craftcms

craft 3 CMS dont run on production "Craft requires PHP 7.0 or later."

Hi,

craft 3 cms dont run on production and my php -v answer this message

```
PHP 7.0.30-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli)
```

Can you help me with this?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I could solve by enabling version 7 with the following commands

```
a2dismod php5

a2enmod php7.0

sevice apache2 restart
```